# Match array elements in arbitray order with string

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to python and trying to find if a tweet has any of the lookup elements.

For eg.  If i can find the word cat it should match cats also cute kittens can be matched in any arbitrary order. But from I've understand I'm not being able to find a solution. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
import re
lookup_table = ['cats', 'cute kittens', 'dog litter park']
tweets = ['that is a cute cat',
          'kittens are cute',
          'that is a cute kitten',
          'that is a dog litter park',
          'no wonder that dog park is bad']
for tweet in tweets:
    lookup_found = None
    print re.findall(r"(?=(" + '|'.join(lookup_table) + r"))", tweet.lower())
```

Output

```
['cat']
[]
[]
['dog litter park']
[]
```

Expected output:

```
that is a cute cat > cats
kittens are cute > cute kittens
this is a cute kitten > cute kittens
that is a dog litter park > dog litter park
no wonder that dog park is bad > dog litter park
```

Comment: ?? use the singular form.

Comment: You should also tell us the output that you actually want.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: @PM2Ring sure, just added the expected output.

Comment: Why does the last tweet match? It doesn't contain "litter". If the reason for that is that all words in a lookup string don't need to match, why then doesn't the first tweet match both  'cats' _and_  'cute kittens'?

Comment: @PM2Ring Where did you see first tweet matching 2 entries? It only matches one.

Comment: The first tweet contains both 'cute' _and_ 'cat'. So why doesn't it match both 'cats' and 'cute kittens' if 'no wonder that dog park is bad' matches 'dog litter park' even though that tweet doesn't contain 'litter'?

Comment: Hmmm.. fairly misleading example output... should it return true if "all" words are present in *any order* or "any" word is present.

Answer (score 0):

For lookup words which are only one word text, you can use

```
for word in tweet
```

And for lookup words like "cute kitten", where you expect any order. Just split the word and look for it in the tweet string.

here is what i tried, its not efficient but its working. Try running it.

```
lookup_table = ['cat', 'cute kitten', 'dog litter park']
tweets = ['that is a cute cat',
          'kittens are cute',
          'that is a cute kitten',
          'that is a dog litter park',
          'no wonder that dog park is bad']

for word in lookup_table:
    for tweet in tweets:
        if " " in word:
            temp = word.split(sep=" ")
        else:
            temp = [word]
        for x in temp:
            if x in tweet:
                print(tweet)
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it. I think the lookup_table need not be too strict and we can avoid the plurals;

```
import re
lookup_table = ['cat', 'cute kitten', 'dog litter park']
tweets = ['that is a cute cat',
      'kittens are cute',
      'that is a cute kitten',
      'that is a dog litter park',
      'no wonder that dog park is bad']
for data in lookup_table:
    words=data.split(" ")
    for word in words:
        result=re.findall(r'[\w\s]*' + word + '[\w\s]*',','.join(tweets))
        if len(result)>0:
            print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:

*Singular/Plural:* 
Just to get things rolling I would use inflect, a python package to get rid of singular & plural and such...

Problem 2:

*Splitting and Joining:*
I wrote a small script to demonstrate how you can use it, not robustly tested but should get you moving

```
import inflect 
p = inflect.engine()
lookup_table = ['cats', 'cute kittens', 'dog litter park']
tweets = ['that is a cute cat',
          'kittens are cute',
          'that is a cute kitten',
          'that is a dog litter park',
          'no wonder that dog park is bad']

for tweet in tweets:
    matched = []
    for lt in lookup_table:
            match_result = [lt for mt in lt.split() for word in tweet.split() if p.compare(word, mt)]
            if any(match_result):
                matched.append(" ".join(match_result))
    print tweet, '>>' , matched
```